# Error socketio en computer engine de google

Tags: nodejs, socket.io, websocket, google-cloud-platform, redis

Alquien a logrado integrar socket.io en una compute engine  de google ?¿?
lo que pasa es que estoy intentado integra pero no se conecta el cliente

main.blade.php

```
window.socket = io("{{env('SOCKET_URL')}}:{{env('SOCKET_PORT')}}");
window.channel = "channel.root";
```

en la variables env('SOCKET_URL') e probado con todo desde el dominio, el localhost, la ip local y la ip interna y externa del compute engine .

en env('SOCKET_PORT') utilizo el puerto 8181

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('channel.root', function(err, count) {
    console.log('Subscribe on test-channel');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connection user');
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved');
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);

    var data = message.data.order;
    var id = data.restaurant_id;
    var check = data.order_check;

    if(check == 0){
        io.emit('channel.' + id + ':' + message.event, message.data);
    }
});

http.listen(8181, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 8181');
});
```

Y me da el sieguiente error ya que no logra conectarse

```
GET http://backoffice.com:8181/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LghumLo net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

alquien sabes cual puede ser el problema o como puede resolverlo.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo habilitado websocket en mi computer engine de google lo unico que e necesito es tener abierto el puerto mediante la consola de google

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create nombrepuerto --allow tcp:8181
```